# undefined method `course_id' for #<Set: {"7"}>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, set, session-variables

Okay so I have a Courses, students, and registrations table. I allow the student to login and their info is stored in a session variable.they can search for courses, choose ones they want which puts the course_id into a session variable. then after they put the courses in a chosen_courses page, they can click the register button to register them for the courses. This is supposed to take the course_id from the session[:course] and the student_id from the session[:student_id] and put them into one table called registrations. The course_id is a set and i know that I am supposed to loop through each course_id and add it to the table but I am not able to. I have posted my controller below and here are the files [THE FILES ARE HERE!!!!](https://rapidshare.com/files/1176690258/hw3_wood.zip)
HERE IS THE CONTROLLER WITH CODE THAT PUTS COURSE_ID AND STUDENT_ID IN DATABASE FROM SESSIONS:

```
  def show 
  @register = Registration.new
  while session[:course].course_id != nill do             
      @register.student_id = session[:student_id].student_id
      @register.course_id = session[:course].course_id       
  end     
   @register.save
  end
```

HERE IS THE VIEW THAT DISPLAYS THE DATA FROM THE registrations database:

```
<% @register.each do |register| %>
<tr>
   <td><%= register.student_id %></td>
   <td><%= register.course_id %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you setting `@registers` in the controller?

Comment: First off, you're setting using = instead of adding to a set, if it's really a set. Second, if you want to display them all, you need to loop over the set.

Comment: I hope `nill` is a typo in the pasted example because the keyword is `nil`. Your use of `while` also seems broken and should be an `if` instead since you're not looping: `if (session[:course].course_id) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put models in your `session` so you can't access them like that. You need to load in anything you need based on the `id` stashed in there.

Here's what I think you're shooting for:

```
def show 
  @register = Registration.new

  if (session[:course_id])
    if (course = Course.find_by_id(session[:course_id]))
      @register.student_id = course.student_id
      @register.course = course
    end
  end

  @register.save
end
```

Be sure to save only the course ID in the session and not the course itself.

Comment: Remember to set `session[:course_id] = @course.id` in an earlier request, or whatever variable stores your course.